How can I record videos like this one?
I want to produce interactive videos of a few minutes like the one in the link. Is it possible to do this for free, how and with which applications?
See

This video is mostly a screen recording, with the mouse cursor recorded separately from the screen itself. Software like ScreenFlow can do this. The "zoom in and move" animations, along with the gradient background could have been made in After Effects.
If you're on a budget, you could make something similar using the built in Screen Recorder in Quicktime Player and animate it afterwards using the free Davinci Resolve, or another free editor like CapCut.
The video isn't "interactive" in the traditional sense - a user presses play then watches the video linearly. It's no Bandersnatch.
